# Is it possible to reference an .env variable inside another .env variable

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I have this little `.env` file for a `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
POSTGRES_USER="root"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="s3cr3t_p4ssw0rd"
POSTGRES_DB="test"
POSTGRESQL_URL="postgresql://root:s3cr3t_p4ssw0rd@localhost:5432/test?schema=public"
```

I would like to reference the `POSTGRES_` variables inside `POSTGRESQL_URL`.

From what I know, this is not possible, because the `.env` file is only a text file with key-value pairs.

Is it now possible? Or can Docker understand it?

This is a question about docker, but I would like to know if it is possible in bash or other environments

Comment: can you just create the POSTGRESQL_URL env variable in the Dockerfile?

Comment: @TomMcLean I use the env variable in other files, not only in the Dockerfile

Comment: But once it is an environment variable, then you no longer need to read the .env file? The only other option I can think of is build the .env file in a CD/CI pipeline stage